# Can the vertices of three squares erected on the edges of a non-isosceles triangle lie on a conic?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

I came up with this guess about three years ago, but I wrote it down for the first time about two months ago, and I don’t know how it can be proven, nor whether it was previously discovered or not. Whoever can help, please do so, thank you.

[image]

It is impossible for the six points to lie on a conic section if the triangle is not isosceles

Comment: Shouldn't we narrow it down to ellipses rather than conic sections? Parabolas and hyperbolas obviously won't work, and circles won't work unless the triangle is equilateral. Also, is the inverse supposed to be always true? In other words, is it always possible to draw an ellipse through all six points if the triangle is indeed isosceles?

Comment: Yes, in fact I forgot to write that, but it is assumed that the property is true from both sides. Proving the matter from the other side is not difficult. I will write it later, God willing. Indeed, the scope can be narrowed to an ellipse, but the impossibility for the sake of the three conic sections is considered more beautiful.  For the base case

Comment: Since any triangle can be transformed into a right triangle, it is sufficient to prove the conjecture for a right triangle.   Namely, prove that the six vertices will lie on an ellipse if and only if the two legs of the right triangle are equal.

Comment: @HosamHAJEER: Transforming the triangle into a right triangle will transform the squares into parallelograms, which changes the problem.

Comment: You're right.  My bad.

Comment: Do you know the existence of the "International Journal of Computer Discovered Mathematics" : https://sites.google.com/view/ijcdm/home ?

Answer (score 6):

Defining $\triangle ABC$ by
$$A=(0,0) \qquad B=(c,0) \qquad C=(b\cos A, b\sin A) \tag{1}$$
we can express the coordinates of the six points as
$$\begin{align}
A+(A-B)^\perp \quad B+(A-B)^\perp \\
B+(B-C)^\perp \quad C+(B-C)^\perp \\
C+(C-A)^\perp \quad A+(C-A)^\perp
\end{align} \tag{2}$$
where $v^\perp:= (-v_y,v_x)$ is the $90^\circ$ counter-clockwise rotation of vector $v$. Then, we recall that points $P$, $Q$, $R$, $S$, $T$, $U$ are co-conicial if and only if
$$\left|
\begin{array}{cccccc} 
P_x^2 & P_y^2 & P_x P_y & P_x & P_y & 1 \\ 
Q_x^2 & Q_y^2 & Q_x Q_y & Q_x & Q_y & 1 \\ 
R_x^2 & R_y^2 & R_x R_y & R_x & R_y & 1 \\ 
S_x^2 & S_y^2 & S_x S_y & S_x & S_y & 1 \\ 
T_x^2 & T_y^2 & T_x T_y & T_x & T_y & 1 \\
U_x^2 & U_y^2 & U_x U_y & U_x & U_y & 1 
\end{array} \right| = 0 \tag{3}$$

A computer algebra system makes light work of expanding and simplifying the determinant condition to
$$\left(a^2-b^2\right)\left(b^2-c^2\right)\left(c^2-a^2\right)\left(a^2+b^2+c^2+8bc\sin A\right) = 0 \tag{4}$$
Since the last factor is strictly positive, the condition is satisfied when, and only when, at least two of $a$, $b$, $c$ are equal: the triangle must be isosceles, so your guess was correct!

I don't doubt that this result exists in the literature somewhere, but that wouldn't diminish your insight.

---

**Note:** If the squares are attached "the other way", so that each overlaps the triangle itself, then we change the "$+$"s in $(2)$ to "$-$"s, and the counterpart of $(4)$ becomes:
$$\left(a^2-b^2\right)\left(b^2-c^2\right)\left(c^2-a^2\right)\left(a^2+b^2+c^2-8bc\sin A\right) = 0 \tag{5}$$
The sign change in that last factor is crucial, as it allows for a continuum of non-isosceles solution triangles.

Comment: I have a different solution that I will post later on...

Comment: Playing around w/ geogebra, it looks like last factor in (5) vanishes when the "conic" degenerate to a pair of lines.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this solution is very similar to the solution given @Blue. I just take a different parametrization, and the determinantal condition I use deals with a $4 \times 4$ determinant. But I use as well a CAS and get also a final condition where the determinant has a nice factorization, the different factors accounting for the different ways triangle $ABC$ is isosceles.

Consider the following figure

[image]

Fig. 1 : A particular case where an ellipse through the given points $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2,C_1,C_2$ exists because $AB=AC$.

where, without loss of generality, we have taken the midpoint of $AB$ as the origin, the other vertices of the square built on $AB$ being $C_1=(-1,-2)$ and $C_2=(1,-2)$. Let

$$\vec{AC}=\pmatrix{u\\v}, \ \ \ \vec{BC}=\pmatrix{u-2\\v}$$

($v$ assumed $>0$, of course). As a consequence, the coordinates of the four other vertices are :

$$A_1=\pmatrix{1+v\\2-u}, \ A_2=\pmatrix{u+v-1\\2-u+v}\tag{1a}$$

$$B_1=\pmatrix{-1-v\\u}, \ B_2=\pmatrix{-1+u-v\\u+v}\tag{1b}$$

The general equation of a conic curve being ;

$$ax^2+by^2+2cxy+2dx+2ey+f=0$$

Taking into account the fact that the conic curve passes through $C_1$ and $C_2$, this equation can be reduced to :

$$(4e-4b-f)x^2+by^2+2cxy+4cx+2ey+f=0 \tag{2}$$

with four unknowns $b,c,e,f$. If we plug in (2) the different values $x=1+v, y=2-u$, etc... issued from (1a) and (1b), we get a linear system of four equations with four unknowns, which has a non-trivial solution iff its determinant is $0$.

Using a CAS (see below), this determinant can be obtained under a factorized form :

$$16(u-1)(u^2+v^2-4)(u^2+v^2-4u)\underbrace{(u^2+v^2-2u+8v+4)}_{(u-1)^2+3+v^2+8v > 0}\tag{3}$$

Its different factors can be placed in correspondence with the 3 different cases where triangle $ABC$ is "isosceles" :

$$\begin{cases}u&=&1\ \leftrightarrow \ AC=BC\\
u^2+v^2&=&4 \ \leftrightarrow \ AB=AC\\u^2+v^2-4u&=&0 \ \leftrightarrow \ AB=BC\end{cases}$$

SAGE program which has given formula (3)

```
 A.<u,v>=QQ[]
 B.<b,c,e,x,y>=A[]
 ex=(4*e-4*b-1)*x^2+b*y^2+2*c*x*y+4*c*x+2*e*y+1;
 A1=ex.subs(x=1+v,y=2-u);a1=A1.coefficients();
 A2=ex.subs(x=u+v-1,y=2-u+v);a2=A2.coefficients();
 B1=ex.subs(x=-1-v,y=u);b1=B1.coefficients();
 B2=ex.subs(x=-1+u+v,y=u+v);b2=B2.coefficients();
 M=matrix([a1,a2,b1,b2]);d=M.determinant();df=factor(d);df
```

(where in particular "subs" means "substitution").

You can execute this code **yourself** : just

1. call https://sagecell.sagemath.org/
2. copy this program into the edit window
3. then press "Evaluate" ;

Comment: I have added the SAGE code and the way to execute it from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of an isosceles triangle, will there be a conic section that passes through the six points?  Yes, this can be easily proven, more generally according to the inverse of Pascal's theorem

Note that any six points with an axis of symmetry that does not pass through any of them will lie on a conic section

[image]